# Plotting results of logistic regression with binomial data from mixed effects model (lme4) with model averaging (MuMIn)

Tags: r, plot, predict, lme4, mumin

I'm trying to display the results of a logistic regression. My model was fit using glmer() from the lme4 package, I then used MuMIn for model averaging.

Simplified version of my model using the `mtcars` dataset:

```
glmer(vs ~ wt +  am + (1|carb), database, family = binomial, na.action = "na.fail")
```

My desired output is two plots that show the predicted probability that `vs`=1, one for `wt`, which is continuous, one for `am`, which is binomial.

I got this much working after comments from @KamilBartoń:

```
database <- mtcars

# Scale data
database$wt <- scale(mtcars$wt)
database$am <- scale(mtcars$am)

# Make global model
model.1 <- glmer(vs ~ wt + am + (1|carb), database, family = binomial, na.action = "na.fail")

# Model selection
model.1.set <- dredge(model.1, rank = "AICc")

# Get models with <10 delta AICc
top.models.1 <- get.models(model.1.set,subset = delta<10)

# Model averaging
model.1.avg <- model.avg(top.models.1)

# make dataframe with all values set to their mean
xweight <- as.data.frame(lapply(lapply(database[, -1], mean), rep, 100))

# add new sequence of wt to xweight along range of data
xweight$wt <- (wt = seq(min(database$wt), max(database$wt), length = 100))

# predict new values
yweight <- predict(model.1.avg, newdata = xweight, type="response", re.form=NA)

# Make plot 
plot(database$wt, database$vs, pch = 20, xlab = "WEIGHT (g)", ylab = "VS")

# Add predicted line
lines(xweight$wt, yweight)
```

Produces:

[image]

The remaining issue is that the data are scaled and centred around 0, meaning interpretation of the graph is impossible. I'm able to unscale the data using an answer from @BenBolker to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53324971/back-transform-coefficients-from-glmer-with-scaled-independent-variables-for-pre/53735644#53735644) but this does not display correctly:

```
## Ben Bolker's unscale function:
## scale variable x using center/scale attributes of variable y
scfun <- function(x,y) {
  scale(x,
        center=attr(y,"scaled:center"),
        scale=attr(y,"scaled:scale"))
        }

## scale prediction frame with scale values of original data -- for all variables
xweight_sc <- transform(xweight,
                        wt = scfun(wt, database$wt),
                        am = scfun(am, database$am))

# predict new values
yweight <- predict(model.1.avg, newdata = xweight_sc, type="response", re.form=NA)

# Make plot 
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$vs, pch = 20, xlab = "WEIGHT (g)", ylab = "VS")

# Add predicted line
lines(xweight$wt, yweight)
```

Produces:

[image]

I've tried this a few different ways but can't work out what the problem is. **What have I done wrong?**

Also, another remaining issue: **How do I make a binomial plot for `am`?**

Comment: You need to provide `predict` with all the independent variables the model uses: `wt`, `am` and possibly also `carb` (if you wish to predict with random effects).

Comment: Thanks @Kamil Bartoń. That makes sense but how would I do this? I've had a play but can't get it to work. I've also looked at the example you gave in the MuMIn documentation but haven't managed to apply it to my data successfully

Comment: It is explained in `?predict.glm`: `newdata` argument is "a `data frame` in which to look for variables with which to predict. If omitted, the fitted linear predictors are used." So you need to create a  `data.frame` (obviously `list` does it as well) that holds all the required variables, all of the same length. With your current code, `predict` finds `wt` of length 47 in `newdata` and finds `am` and `carb` elsewhere, possibly in the original `data` which has a different length (7). Hence the error.

Comment: OK thanks. I've tried making a dataframe with the required variables: `xweight <- data.frame(wt=seq(-2, 2.5, 0.1),carb=seq(0, 8, 0.175),am=seq(0, 1, 0.022))`, now when I run `yweight <- predict(model.1.avg, newdata = xweight, type="response")` I get a different error `1: In levelfun(r, n, allow.new.levels = allow.new.levels) :  new levels detected in newdata`. Sorry if these are basic mistakes I'm making

Comment: Your new grouping variable's levels (`carb`) have to be a subset of the original ones. You cannot predict for unknown groups.

Comment: OK great, thanks. So if I set all `carb` entries to 1: `xweight <- data.frame(wt=seq(-2, 2.5, 0.23),carb=1,am=seq(0, 1, 0.052))` it seems to work and produces a plot but I'm not sure exactly what I've done - is this correct?

Comment: You should decide whether you want predictions with or without random effects included. Read about `re.form` in `?predict.merMod`.

Comment: OK thanks @KamilBartoń. It seems to be working now but I'm not convinced my code is without errors. I've updated the question.

Comment: You probably don't want to predict along both gradients of `wt` and `am`. It is more useful to set other variables to some fixed value(s) (e.g. mean).
Alternatively, you can plot effects (see package `effects`). 
Also note that now your predictions are for only one group (carb=1), unless you set `re.form` to `NA`, which will give you the mean without RE.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a bit more sense now

Comment: @KamilBartoń - is it possible to unscale coefficients for prediction? (see updated question). I know you can scale variables in MuMIn using `stdize` or `beta = c("none", "sd", "partial.sd")`, is there a way to back-transform?

Comment: Perhaps the simplest way is to scale the new data before prediction using the original center and scale. See `?stdize` and it's argument `source`. Otherwise, the `scale`d/`stdize`d variables have two attributes `"scaled:center"` and `"scaled:scale"` which allow you to untransform.

Comment: @KamilBartoń thanks, I've tried using the scale attributes to untransform but it doesn't work. I've posted an example in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53324971/1640528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## setup

```
library(lme4)
library(MuMIn)
database <- mtcars
database$wt <- scale(mtcars$wt)
database$am <- scale(mtcars$am)
model.1 <- glmer(vs ~ wt + am + (1|carb), database, family = binomial, na.action = "na.fail")
model.1.set <- dredge(model.1, rank = "AICc")
top.models.1 <- get.models(model.1.set,subset = delta<10)
model.1.avg <- model.avg(top.models.1)
```

## Answer

The problem at hand seems to be creating a graph of the average effect similar to the `effects` package (or the  `ggeffects` package). Thomas got pretty close, but a small misunderstanding of [Ben Bolkers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53735644/10782538) answer, has led to inverting the scaling process, which in this case led to double scaling of parameters. This can be seen illustrated below by snippeting out the code above.

```
database$wt <- scale(mtcars$wt)
database$am <- scale(mtcars$am)

# More code

xweight <- as.data.frame(lapply(lapply(database[, -1], mean), rep, 100))
xweight$wt <- (wt = seq(min(database$wt), max(database$wt), length = 100))

# more code 

scfun <- function(x,y) {
  scale(x,
        center=attr(y,"scaled:center"),
        scale=attr(y,"scaled:scale"))
        }
xweight_sc <- transform(xweight,
                        wt = scfun(wt, database$wt),
                        am = scfun(am, database$am))
```

From this we see that `xweight` is actually already scaled, and thus the second time scaling is used, we obtain

```
sc <- attr(database$wt, 'scaled:scale')
ce <- attr(database$wt, 'scaled:center')
xweight_sc$wt <- scale(scale(seq(min(mtcars$wt), max(mtcars$wt), ce, sc), ce, sc)
```

What [Ben Bolker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53735644/10782538) is talking about in his answer however, is the situation where a model uses scaled predictors while the data used for prediction was not. In this case the data is scaled correctly, but one wishes to interpret it for the original scale. We simply have to invert the process. For this one could use 2 methods.

## Method 1: changing breaks in ggplot

note: One could use custom labels in `xlab` in base R.

One method for changing the axis is to.. change the axis. This allows one to keep the data  and only rescale the labels.

```
# Extract scales
sc <- attr(database$wt, 'scaled:scale')
ce <- attr(database$wt, 'scaled:center')
# Create plotting and predict data
n <- 100
pred_data <- aggregate(. ~ 1, data = mtcars, FUN = mean)[rep(1, 100), ]
pred_data$wt <- seq(min(database$wt), max(database$wt), length = n)
pred_data$vs <- predict(model.1.avg, newdata = pred_data, type = 'response', re.form = NA)  
# Create breaks
library(scales) #for pretty_breaks and label_number
breaks <- pretty_breaks()(pred_data$wt, 4) #4 is abritrary
# Unscale the breaks to be used as labels
labels <- label_number()(breaks * sc + ce) #See method 2 for explanation
# Finaly we plot the result
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = pred_data, aes(x = wt, y = vs)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(data = database) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels) #to change labels.
```

which is the desired result. Note that there is no confidence bands, that is due to the lack of a closed-form for the confidence intervals for the original model, and it seems likely that the best method to get any estimate at all, is to use bootstrapping.

### method 2: Unscaling

In unscaling we simply invert the process of `scale`. As `scale(x)= (x - mean(x))/sd(x)` we simply have to isolate x: `x = scale(x) * sd(x) + mean(x)`, and this is the process to be done, but still remember to use the scaled data during prediction:

```
# unscale the variables 
pred_data$wt <- pred_data$wt * sc + ce
database$wt <- database$wt * sc + ce

# Finally plot the result
ggplot(data = pred_data, aes(x = wt, y = vs)) + 
         geom_line() + 
         geom_point(data = database)
```

which is the desired result.

Comment: Thanks @Oliver, just what I was after. There's still an unanswered question though - how do I make a binomial plot for `am`? I don't know where to start with this. And is there any chance you could elaborate on the comment about bootstrapping (some code)?

Comment: Hi @Thomas. Sorry I missed this part of your question. Very briefly, the problem for factors (eg. `am`) is what to visualize. If they are indeed factors (here I used them as Numeric) they would not be scaled. So simply: 1) Use the mean for all numeric variables, 2) for all other factors, use the base level `levels(factor)[1]`, 3) predict using `predict` on this dataset, and then plot the result.  There will only be 1 point for each level in the factor.

Comment: Any chance you could add the code for this to your answer? I will then accept as answer. Thanks

Comment: I'll add another answer later this evening (like 12 hours from now) with an example of plotting a factor (`am`) and parametric/non-parametric bootstrapping. :-)

Answer (score 2):

## setup

```
library(lme4)
library(MuMIn)
database <- mtcars
database$wt <- scale(mtcars$wt)
database$am <- factor(mtcars$am) ## <== note the difference here. It is a factor not numeric
model.1 <- glmer(vs ~ wt + am + (1|carb), database, family = binomial, na.action = "na.fail")
model.1.set <- dredge(model.1, rank = "AICc")
top.models.1 <- get.models(model.1.set,subset = delta<10)
model.1.avg <- model.avg(top.models.1)
nPoints <- 100
wt_pred_data <- data.frame(wt = seq(min(database$wt), max(database$wt), length = nPoints),
                           am = database$am[which.min(database$am)], #Base level for the factor
                           var = 'wt')
am_pred_data <- data.frame(wt = mean(database$wt), 
                           am = unique(database$am),
                           var = 'am')
pred_data <- rbind(wt_pred_data, am_pred_data)
rm(wt_pred_data, am_pred_data)
pred_data$vs <- predict(model.1.avg, newdata = pred_data, re.form = NA, type = 'response')
```

## actual answer

Adding to my previous answer, as Thomas seems interested in how one would deal with `factor`s and also how one obtains confidence intervals using bootstraps.

## Dealing with factors

First dealing with factors is not much harder than dealing with the numeric variables. The difference here is that

1. When plotting effects on numeric variables, factors should be set to their base level (eg. for `am` as a factor this would be a value of 1)
2. When plotting the factors, one sets all numeric variables to their mean, and all other factors to their base level.

One method for getting the base level of a factor is `factor[which.min(factor)]` and yet another is `factor(levels(factor)[0], levels(factor))`. The `ggeffects` package uses some method similar to this.

## bootstrapping

Now bootstrapping in practice ranges from being easy, to difficult. One can either use parametric, semi-parametric or non-parametric bootstraps.
Non-parametric bootstrap is the easiest to explain. One simply takes a sample of the original dataset (say 2/3, 3/4 or 4/5. Less can be used for "good" larger datasets), refits the model using this sample and then predicts for this new model. Then one repeats the process N times, and uses this to estimate standard deviation or quantiles and uses this for confidence intervals. There seems to be no implemented method in `MuMIn` to take care of this for us, so we seem to have to handle this ourselves.
Usually code gets quite messy, and using a function makes it much clearer. To my frustration the `MuMIn` seemed to have problems with this however, so below is a non-functional way of doing this. In this code I choose a sample size of 4/5, because the dataset size is rather small.

```
###                            ###
## Non-parametric bootstrapping ##
## Note: Gibberish with         ##
##       singular fit!          ##
###                            ###

# 1) Create sub-sample from the dataset (eg 2/3, 3/4 or 4/5 of the original dataset)
# 2) refit the model using the new dataset and estimate model average using this dataset
# 3) estimate the predicted values using the refitted model
# 4) refit the model N times

nBoot <- 100
frac <- 4/5 #number of points in each sample. Better datasets can use less.
bootStraps <- vector('list', nBoot)
shutup <- function(x) #Useful helper function for making a function shut up
  suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(force(x)))
ii <- seq_len(n <- nrow(database))
nn <- ceiling(frac * n)
nb <- nn * nBoot
samples <- sample(ii, nb, TRUE)
samples <- split(samples, (nn + seq_len(nb) - 1) %/% nn) #See unique((nn + seq_len(nb) - 1) %/% nn) # <= Gives 1 - 100.
#Not run:
# lengths(samples) # <== all of them are 26 long! ceiling(frac * n) = 26!
# Run the bootstraps
for(i in seq_len(nBoot)){
  preds <- try({
    # 1) Sample 
    d <- database[samples[[i]], ]
    # 2) fit the model using the sample
    bootFit <- shutup(glmer(vs ~ wt + am + (1|carb), d, family = binomial, na.action = "na.fail"))
    bootAvg <- shutup(model.avg(get.models(dredge(bootFit, rank = 'AICc'), subset = delta < 10)))
    # 3) predict the data using the new model
    shutup(predict(bootAvg, newdata = pred_data, re.form = NA, type = 'response'))
  }, silent = TRUE)
  #save the predictions for later
  if(!inherits(preds, 'try-error'))
    bootStraps[[i]] <- preds
  # repeat N times
}
# Number of failed bootStraps:
sum(failed <- sapply(bootStraps, is.null)) #For me 44, but will be different for different datasets, samples and seeds.
bootStraps <- bootStraps[which(!failed)]
alpha <- 0.05
# 4) use the predictions for calculating bootstrapped intervals
quantiles <- apply(do.call(rbind, bootStraps), 2, quantile, probs = c(alpha / 2, 0.5, 1 - alpha / 2))
pred_data[, c('lower', 'median', 'upper')] <-  t(quantiles)
pred_data[, 'type'] <- 'non-parametric'
```

Take note that this is of course total gibberish. The fit is singular because `mtcars` is not a dataset showing mixed effects, so the bootstrapping confidence intervals **will** be completely out of wack (the range of values are too spread out). Do also note that for such an unstable dataset as this, quite a few bootstraps fail to converge into something sensible.

For parametric bootstraps we can turn to `lme4::bootMer`. This function takes a single `merMod` model (`glmer` or `lmer` result) as well as a function to be evaluated on each parametric refit. So creating this function `bootMer` can take care of the rest. We are interested in the predicted values, so the function should return these. Note the similarity of the function, to the above method

```
###                     ###
## Parametric bootstraps ##
## Note: Singular fit    ##
##       makes this      ##
##       useless!        ##
###                     ###
bootFun <- function(model){
  preds <- try({
    bootAvg <- shutup(model.avg(get.models(dredge(model, rank = 'AICc'), subset = delta < 10)))
    shutup(predict(bootAvg, newdata = pred_data, re.form = NA, type = 'response'))
  }, silent = FALSE)
  if(!inherits(preds, 'try-error'))
    return(preds)
  return(rep(NA_real_, nrow(pred_data)))
}
boots <- bootMer(model.1, FUN = bootFun, nsim = 100, re.form = NA, type = 'parametric')
quantiles <- apply(boots$t, 2, quantile, probs = c(alpha / 2, 0.5, 1 - alpha / 2), na.rm = TRUE)
# Create data to be predicted with parametric bootstraps
pred_data_p <- pred_data
pred_data_p[, c('lower', 'median', 'upper')] <- t(quantiles)
pred_data_p[, 'type'] <- 'parametric'
pred_data <- rbind(pred_data, pred_data_p)
rm(pred_data_p)
```

Note again, that due to the singularity the result will be gibberish. In this case the result will be way too certain, as singularity means the model is going to be way too accurate on known data. So in practice this would make the range of every interval 0 or close enough that it makes no difference.

Finally we just need to plot the results. We can use `facet_wrap` to compare the parametric and non-parametric results. Note again, that for this specific dataset, it is very much gibberish to compare the confidence intervals which are both completely useless.

Note that for the factor `am` i use `geom_point` and `geom_errorbar` where i use `geom_line` and `geom_ribbon` for numeric values, to better represent the grouped nature of a factor compared to the continuous nature of a numeric variable

```
#Finaly we can plot our result:
# wt
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(pred_data[pred_data$var == 'wt', ], aes(y = vs, x = wt)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower), alpha = 0.2) + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ type) + 
  ggtitle('gibberish numeric plot (caused by singularity in fit)')

# am
ggplot(pred_data[pred_data$var == 'am', ], aes(y = vs, x = am)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = upper, ymin = lower)) + 
  facet_wrap(. ~ type) + 
  ggtitle('gibberish factor plot (caused by singularity in fit)')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/) for this, either with `ggpredict()` or `ggeffect()` (see `?ggpredict` for the difference for these two functions, the first calls `predict()`, the latter `effects::Effect()`).

```
library(ggeffects)
library(sjmisc)
library(lme4)
data(mtcars)

mtcars <- std(mtcars, wt)
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

m <- glmer(vs ~ wt_z + am + (1|carb), mtcars, family = binomial, na.action = "na.fail")

# Note the use of the "all"-tag here, see help for details
ggpredict(m, "wt_z [all]") %>% plot()
```

[image]

```
ggpredict(m, "am") %>% plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesn't fix my problem - `ggpredict()` doesn't work with `model.avg` (unless I'm mistaken?)

Comment: This would be perfect if it worked with MuMIn. Is there a package like this that works with model averaging?